# Confusing behavior of stdout/stderr and /dev/null

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to understand a command like

```
[command] > /dev/null 2>&1
```

If I understand this correctly, the output of the command is redirected to `/dev/null` and then the `stderr` (file descriptor 2) is redirected to `stdout` (file descriptor 1)

The end result is, only errors of `[command]` will be output

To understand this, I executed the following commands:

```
bash-3.2$ echo "Hello World" 1>&2
Hello World
```

Here, I am echoing "Hello World" and redirecting it to `stderr`.
And now I run the following:

```
bash-3.2$ echo "Hello World" 1>&2 2>&1
Hello World
```

I am taking the `stderr` and redirecting it to `stdout`. And as expected, it prints `Hello World`

Now I run this

```
bash-3.2$ echo "Hello World" 1>&2 1>&1
Hello World
```

What I am trying to do is to printout `stdout`.
However, there is no `stdout` since I redirected it to `stderr`.

So why is it printing `Hello World`?
I would have expected it to print nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "Hello World" 1>&2 1>&1
```

redirects file descriptor 1 (standard out) to whatever file descriptor 2 (standard error) is pointing at, and then redirects file descriptor 1 to itself. All the output thus goes to standard error, but you haven’t changed that — so it all goes to your current terminal.

To print nothing, you need to redirect standard error:

```
(echo "Hello World" 1>&2 1>&1) 2> /dev/null
```

or equivalently,

```
echo "Hello World" 2>/dev/null 1>&2
```

Your interpretation of

```
[command] > /dev/null 2>&1
```

isn’t accurate: `> /dev/null` redirects standard output to `/dev/null`, and then redirects standard error to what standard output is currently pointing at, `/dev/null`. So all the output is discarded.

See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440) for details.